# Remove active class on specific div with URL hash

Tags: javascript, php, css, owl-carousel

I made page with owl carousel Url Hash Navigation need remove active class on a specific div

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    $('span').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

this will remove class form every li Tag

But i need remove class on a specific div element

i have try this

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $( '#ma a' ).on( 'hashchange', function(e){
    $('#ma span').closest('li').removeClass('active');
 });
 $( '#mc a' ).on( 'hashchange', function(e){
     $('#mc span').closest('li').removeClass('active');
 });
let hash = window.location.hash;
$('a[href="' + hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

});

this is live page link 
 https://www.unityonecloud.com/features

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your original code will work but you will want to use a more specific selector when removing the "active" class.  Looking at the site you provided something like this would work:

```js
$('#fbar2 span li').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: hi in my code #fbar2 is complte div id can you guide me more